Pass array values as parameter to azure devops yaml template
We are getting a list of pom files dynamically from Azure DevOps yaml pipeline task. We need to pass each pom file as a parameter to another yaml template file to build a Java application. Can you please help on this?

Our goal is to get the changed files from the pull request of Azure repo using Azure pipelines. then we only do sonarqube analyse for that maven project only

What is the format of the list you got? - ArrayList

One PowerShell task will collect changed files as ArrayList. I need to pass this to another task

"Pass each pom file as a parameter to another yaml template file" - Is the template you are using in the same pipeline as the task that obtained the pom list? No MainTemplate will have a task that collects all changed files as an array list. Then we will pass each pom file to another template which has a maven task


#Main Template
trigger:
  none
jobs:
- job: 'PSScriptAnalyzer'
  displayName: PSScriptAnalyzer
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'GetChangedFiles'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        pwsh: true
        script: |     
          //it will collet changed files from a azure repo as arraylist from a pull request using azure devops api
          //I can able to get those files. Now need to pass this array list to another template which maven task
          //we will get this values as dynamically.           
          ex: $files = "folder1/pom.xml","folder2/xml"        
    template : maventemplate.yml

      Here i need to pass as parameter**


Can you please show us what you've tried so far and add some code to the question?


"We are getting list of pom files" - What is the format of the list you got? String? Array or something else? Please share a sample with us. 2. "pass each pom file as parameter to another yaml template file" - Is the template you are using in the same pipeline as the task that obtained the pom list? 3. It would be better to share your main yaml and template.


1.Our goal is getting the changed files from pull request of azure repo using azure pipelines. then we only do sonarqube analyse for that maven project only   2.What is the format of the list you got? - Arraylist
3.one powershell task will collect changed files as arraylist. I need to pass this to another task


"pass each pom file as parameter to another yaml template file" - Is the template you are using in the same pipeline as the task that obtained the pom list?

No MainTemplate will have a task that collect all changed files as array list . Then we will pass each pom file to the another template which has maven task

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
displayName: 'GetChangedFiles'
inputs:
targetType: inline
pwsh: true
script: |
//it will collet changed files from a azure repo as arraylist from a pull request using azure devops api
//I can able to get those files. Now need to pass this array list to another template which maven task
//we will get this values as dynamically.
ex: $files = "folder1/pom.xml","folder2/xml"
template : maventemplate.yml
Here i need to pass as parameter

Hi @Learner, have you tried to use the split function of PowerShell and use mvn command to build your projects? See my update Workaround3 below for the example yaml configuration.

Hi @ZiyangLiu-MSFT - It worked fine. Thank you . But i tried another approach from your previous suggestions. But i am not getting any values


task: PowerShell@2
inputs:
targetType: 'inline'
script: |
$paths = "$(changedFiles)"
$pathsArray = $paths -split ' '


foreach($path in $pathsArray)
{
$token = "{PAT}"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
$url="https://dev.azure.com/{Org}/{Project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipeline id}}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview"
$body = @'
{
"stagesToSkip": [],
"resources": {
"repositories": {
"self": {
"refName": "refs/heads/main"
}
}
},

"templateParameters": {
"pomFiles": $path
}
}
'@
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $head -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType application/json
}

“But i tried another approach from your previous suggestions. But i am not getting any values ” - Print the value of $(changedFiles) and $pathsArray in your PowerShell task. Print $path in the loop. Check whether these values are correct. If the values are empty or wrong, correct your scripts. If you have any problem, please create a new question.

Workaround1: Use REST API to trigger your maven pipeline and pass parameter. Use YAML build-in split function to split $files into several pom files.
The main.yaml:

Create output var changedFiles
Run REST API Runs - Run Pipeline to trigger your maven pipeline and pass parameter.

# main.yml
jobs:
- job: 'PSScriptAnalyzer'
  displayName: PSScriptAnalyzer
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $files = "my-app/pom.xml","my-newapp/pom.xml"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=changedFiles]$files"
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $token = "{PAT}"
        $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
        $head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }   
        $url="https://dev.azure.com/{Org}/{Project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipeline id}}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview"           
        $body = @'
        {
            "stagesToSkip": [],
            "resources": {
                "repositories": {
                    "self": {
                        "refName": "refs/heads/main"
                    }
                }
            },
            "templateParameters": {
                "pomFiles": "$(changedFiles)"
            }
        
        }
        '@
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $head -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType application/json

The maven.yml:
# maven.yml

parameters:
  - name: pomFiles
    type: string
    default: pom.xml

trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

jobs:
- job: 'Build'
  displayName: Build
  steps:
    - ${{ each pomfile in split(parameters.pomFiles, ' ') }}:
      - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
          script: 'echo ${{pomfile}}'
      - task: Maven@3
        inputs:
          mavenPomFile: ${{pomfile}}
          goals: 'clean verify'
          options: '-Dmaven.test.skip=true'

Then you can see the following results:


Workaround2: Use array parameter to pass your pom files to avoid using YAML build-in split function.
If you can't use split in your pipeline, you can use array parameter to pass your pom files. But you need to change the definition of your $files to an array.
New main.yaml
- job: 'PSScriptAnalyzer'
  displayName: PSScriptAnalyzer
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $files = @(
          "- my-app/pom.xml"
          "- my-newapp/pom.xml"
        )
        $jsonFiles = $files -join "`r`n" | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=changedFiles]$jsonFiles"
  
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        Write-Host The value of changedFiles is: '$(changedFiles)'
        $token = "{PAT}"
        $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
        $head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }   
        $url="https://{instance}/{collection}/{Proj}/_apis/pipelines/{pipeline id}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview"           
        $body = @'
        {
            "stagesToSkip": [],
            "resources": {
                "repositories": {
                    "self": {
                        "refName": "refs/heads/main"
                    }
                }
            },
            "templateParameters": {
                "pomFiles": $(changedFiles)
            }
        
        }
        '@
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $head -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType application/json

Note: Ensure to define $files with - in its value.
New maven.yml
parameters:
  - name: pomFiles
    type: object
    default:
    - pom.xml
    - pom2.xml

jobs:
- job: 'Build'
  displayName: Build
  steps:
    - ${{ each pomfile in parameters.pomFiles }}:
      - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
          script: 'echo ${{pomfile}}'
      - task: Maven@3
        inputs:
          mavenPomFile: ${{pomfile}}
          goals: 'clean verify'
          options: '-Dmaven.test.skip=true'


Workaround3: Use the default split function in PowerShell and build Maven projects using mvn command line.
The main.yml:
jobs:
- job: 'PSScriptAnalyzer'
  displayName: PSScriptAnalyzer
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    name: setvar
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        # Assume the generated "files" are "my-app/pom.xml", "my-newapp/pom.xml"
        $files = "my-app/pom.xml","my-newapp/pom.xml"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=changedFiles;isoutput=true]$files"
- template: maven.yml
  parameters:
    pomFiles: $[ dependencies.PSScriptAnalyzer.outputs['setvar.changedFiles'] ]

The maven.yml:
parameters:
  - name: pomFiles
    type: string

jobs:
- job: Maven
  dependsOn: PSScriptAnalyzer
  variables:
    pomFiles: ${{parameters.pomFiles}}
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $paths = "$(pomFiles)"
        
        # Split the string into an array of paths
        $pathsArray = $paths -split ' '
        
        # Iterate over each path and invoke Maven with 'clean verify'
        foreach ($path in $pathsArray) {
            Write-Host 'The value of path is:' $path 
            mvn -f $path clean verify
        } 

The result:


Ziyang Liu-MSFT - Thanks. But we can see $(pomFiles) has two pom files. How can i pass each file to maven task? This is my actual issue.

task: Maven@3
inputs:
mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'


If you want to pass each file to maven task, you can use each keyword to loop through parameters. But you need to run your maven task in a separate pipeline. Because your variable is set and expand at runtime, but each expression will read the variable at compile time. See my update above.

Thanks. But i am getting below error. Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1", "innerexception:null","message": "Maven.yml(Line : 17,Col: 7): Unrecognized value: 'split'"


Are you using the yaml files I shared? 2. Have you created a separate pipeline using maven.yml and obtained the pipeline id? You need to run this pipeline at least once to obtain the pipeline id and enter it into the main.yml pipeline.



I am only using the files shared by you. 2. I have created separate pipeline for maven.xml. If i try to run maven.xml i am getting the below error. "Encountered error while parsing the Pipeline YAML. Unrecognized value: 'split'. Located at position 1 within expression: split(parameters.pomFiles, ' ')


I am using Azure Devops Server 2022

According to the yaml shared by you  pool: vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest', you seem to use a MS-hosted agent, which isn't supported in Azure DevOps server. Can you share a screenshot of the error and yourmaven.yml`?

I am using Self-hosted agent which is windows server.  pool:  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest' this is just for example . We are using on-premise version of azure devops server

maven.yml
parameters:

name: pomFiles
type: string
default: pom.xml

trigger:

none

pool:
name: testagent #selfhosted agent
jobs:

job: 'Build'
displayName: Build
steps:

${{ each pomfile in split(parameters.pomFiles, ' ') }}:

task: CmdLine@2
inputs:
script: 'echo ${{pomfile}}'
task: Maven@3
inputs:
mavenPomFile: ${{pomfile}}
goals: 'clean verify'
options: '-Dmaven.test.skip=true'






This is the error for while running maven.yml alone
"Encountered error while parsing the Pipeline YAML. Unrecognized value: 'split'. Located at position 1 within expression: split(parameters.pomFiles, ' ')
Look like there is some issue in split .

According to the doc Azure DevOps server 2022 supports split. I have also tested on my side, it works fine on Server 2022. According to this doc, Azure DevOps Server 2020 doesn't support split.

If you still can't use split, you can use array parameter to pass your pom files. But you need to change the definition of your $files to an array. See my update above.

Thank you very much for your replies. But you have set the values already in the script         $files = @(
"- my-app/pom.xml"
"- my-newapp/pom.xml"
)   But our script will dynamically get the files from powershell script execution $files will be dynamically populate from powershell script

"But you have set the values already in the script $files = @( "- my-app/pom.xml" "- my-newapp/pom.xml" ) " - The value of $files is not pre-set, this is just to give you an example of what format you need to convert $files to, you need to customize the script to do it.

In your another question, you said you were using Azure DevOps Server 2022.0.1, in which YAML doesn't support string split function. But you can use the default split function in PowerShell and call mvn command line to build your project. I have updated in the above answer for this case's situation.
